# BigCommerce Pulling Custom Fields for Listing

Tags: bigcommerce

I have input several custom fields for a client that they want to display in a category listing on the main page.  These categories could be "new products", or product type categories, or whatever.

It's my understanding that BigCommerce doesn't allow this by default (only title, thumbnail, price, and cart link).

Is there another method that can accomplish this same thing?

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways to do this.  you can use ajax to pull them from a static html file which has product ID as the top level element then sub elements contain the extracted custom values.   You can generate this by sequentially running through Get Product API and looking for the "custom_fields" json.  It will contain the field type, label and value.

so you end up with a file with one of these for each product. you ajax the dom object ID and you have your data ready to parse.
    `<object id=1>
       <customValue>
       <type> text </type>
       <label> blah</label>
       <value>somevalue</value>
      </customValue>
      <sku>2103-1335</sku>
    </object>`